# Configuring IntelliJ 14 to debug an externally deployed Glassfish application

Tags: java, deployment, intellij-idea, glassfish

Hi All IntelliJ IDEA experts,

I seek help (if possible please with screenshots) on how to configure  IntelliJ IDEA 14 to just debug a Glassfish 3.1 EAR and WAR

App deployed externally. I mean mvn build and deploy via Glassfish 
Admin console and only debug from IntelliJ .

I go to set a local debug config in Glassfish and it insists on deployment of artifacts (which I do not want to do via IntelliJ)

Reason for not deploying via IntelliJ is that 2 WAR files  depend on the
EAR to be deployed before hand and currently I think IntelliJ (as of version 14) does not let you juggle / or manually sort the deployment order and sorts deployment artifacts by name-wise in the natural sort order (A limitation)

Please help with externally configured artifacts based debug configuration help!

Screenshots for local debug config attached herewith
[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just setting local Glassfish debug configuration is enough. There is no difference if the wars/ears are deployed via IDEA or externally.

The message you refer to "No artifacts marked for deployment" is actually a warning, not an error (although the red color of the icon is confusing). ALthough it appears, it does not stops you from running the debug configuration (just hit OK when the message appears).

Comment: Thanks Ivaylo D. Ivanov. Can you please have a look at the Local Debug configuration screens (tab-wise) update in my original question and let me know if I need to have the debug flag explicitly specified in i.e. `<java-config debug-options="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=9009,server=n,suspend=y" system-classpath="" classpath-suffix="" java-home="C:\Java6\u29">` in my domain config.xml

Comment: Yes, you need these - just leave this tab with defaults. By the way, you still can deploy the wars from IDEA if you rename your wars to match alphabetically their startup order, for example I rename mine as 0-name-of-the-first.war; 1-name-of-the second.war; And already posted a bug to IntelliJ team to add this ordering : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-134958

Comment: Hi Ivaylo D. Ivanov, I can only see     Version: 14.1.4  , Build: 141.1532.4
    Released: June 19th, 2015  available for

Comment: Hi Ivaylo D. Ivanov, I can only see     Version: 14.1.4  , Build: 141.1532.4
    Released: June 19th, 2015  available for. The Youtrack indicate that this has been fixed  on 31 Aug 2015 under Build 142.4465 ? How is that available ? From Check for update within IntelliJ 14.1 also it shows only 14.1.4 build 141.1532 as latest available. Does this mean I have to purchase IntelliJ 15 EAP ? (an expensive proposition)

Comment: Hi @RahulSaini, I'm not the person to answer this question. I've asked them whether this fix will be backported to 14 but so far no answer.

Comment: Hi @Ivaylo D. Ivanov, I got a reply on the same query from Michael Golubev stating that "It seems like a https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137202 which is fixed now and should be available in next IDEA 15 EAP"

Comment: Sorry. That is another one. It is related to Deploy to GlassFish with compatibility property. But, I think they will most likely not backport to 14. Will be available only in 15 EAP (which is sad!)

Answer (score 0):

Delete password in admin configuration.

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBV5M.png)